# Gui programming in python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, graphical-programming

```py
import tkinter as tk
weight = tk(float(input("Enter your weight in kgs : ")))
height = tk(float(input("Enter your height cms : ")))
bmi = weight/ (height/100)**2

if bmi <= 17.5:
    tk(print("You are severely underweight:"))
elif bmi <= 18.5:
    tk(print("You are underweight:"))
elif bmi  <= 25:
    tk(print("You have Normal weight"))
elif bmi <= 30:
    tk(print("You are overweight"))
elif bmi <= 40:
    tk(print("You are obese"))
else:
    tk(print("You are severely obese"))

tk(print(bmi))

m.mainloop()
```

> Enter your weight in kg: 85

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/damanbir singh/Desktop/ffc.py", line 2, in <module>
    weight = tk(float(input("Enter your weight in kgs : ")))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I'm trying to do GUI programming without any knowledge I have got an error.

Comment: You can't just type code that you hope will work. You should start by working through a tkinter tutorial so that you can learn the fundamentals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for starters, everything you did is quite wrong. You should go and read some documentation before trying it out. Putting print and input statements after tk() isn't the way to go.

[Here's some useful information.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm)

Comment: Bro how can I get some projects to enhance my profile.

Comment: agreed but this is this really an answer, for example you don't exactly answer why the error or what should be improved? @DSG also I would suggest tutorials, for starters those may be easier to understand: [tutorial series by Codemy.com on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQSEXcf6s2I&list=PLCC34OHNcOtoC6GglhF3ncJ5rLwQrLGnV)